# sumproduct using multiple criteria + a range

Tags: excel

I have the following sumproduct formula:

```
    =SUMMENPRODUKT(--('[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$A$5:$A$20000=[@[product '#]])*
('[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000=500);
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$D$5:$D$20000)
/SUMMEWENNS('[myworkbook.xlsx]VK averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$A$5:$A$20000;[@[product '#]];
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;500)
```

basically, this is a weighted averages formula, that checks a long list, and matches where the product# is the same (col A), and where the amount is 500 (col E).. and then does the weighted averages calculation.

And it works... However, instead of doing the average on only where the amount is 500 - i'd like to have a range, ie: >100 & <501.

Any ideas on how to do that, in such a setup?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 =SUMMENPRODUKT(--('[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$A$5:$A$20000=[@[product '#]])*
('[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000>100)*
('[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000<501);
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$D$5:$D$20000)
/SUMMEWENNS('[myworkbook.xlsx]VK averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$A$5:$A$20000;[@[product '#]];
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;">100";
'[myworkbook.xlsx]price averages'!$E$5:$E$20000;",501")
```